# multiple stackpanels in ScrollViewer Windows 8 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I seem to be having a problem with adding multiple StackPanels in a ScrollViewer. I can add the first one and it displays the data I want but when I try to add the second StackPanel is fails and brings the error "Duplication assignment to the 'Content' property of the 'ScrollViewer' object"

My front end code is like below:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                    ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Style='{StaticResource BlueFirstStackPanel}'>

                <TextBlock Text='Facility Patient Number:'
                                     Style='{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}' />
                <TextBox Style='{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}' />
                <TextBlock Text='Patient Number:'
                                     Style='{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}' />
                <TextBox Style='{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}' />
                <TextBlock Text='Patient Support Number:'
                                     Style='{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}' />
                <TextBox Style='{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}' />
                <TextBlock Text='NHIF Number:'
                                     Style='{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}' />
                <TextBox Style='{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}' />

                <TextBlock Text='Patient National ID:'
                                     Style='{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}' />
                <TextBox Style='{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}' />

            </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

My C# code for the code has this in it:

```
public sealed class ScrollViewer : ContentControl
        {
        }
```

And the above displays very well but when I add a second StackPanel it brings an error. Any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

The ScrollViewer can only have one child control. Try wrapping both StackPanels in a Grid or another StackPanel:

```
        <ScrollViewer>

            <StackPanel x:Name="ScrollViewerChild">

                <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1">

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel2">

                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
```